# Weblogic 10.3.6 Application starts automatically after activating changes

Tags: java, web, weblogic, web-deployment, weblogic-10.x

In weblogic 10.3.6 after installing the application and activating the changes, the application starts automatically. How do I disable that, so that after activating the changes, i can manually start the application.

It used to work before, but I had to reinstall the web logic and since then application starts automatically. Please help!

Regards,
Arun

Comment: You could always have your managed server down when you deploy... but the answer below is correct, your application should install and sit in the prepared state. How exactly are you deploying it?

Answer (score 0):

Are you deploying the application or installing?

If you deploy the app will be in prepared state so later whenever you want you can start/stop the application....

Comment: I am not sure what the difference between deploying and installing the application.I used to install the application, activate the changes, the installed application will be in prepared state and then start the application. But after re-installing the weblogic, I do the same process, but the application goes to active state after activating the changes.

Comment: I got your problem...please stop the application before installing...once you stop the application it's status will be in "Prepared" status then remove that application and recycle the nodes once...then try to install the application then it must have to be in "prepared" state....

The issue you mentioned above still remaining because you are not stopping the application and you are directly removing the application and installing so it's status is active..do the above steps it will resove the issue

Comment: Tatarao, Thanks for your reply. I normally stop the application before deleting it and then install the application. Is there any configuration change that needs to be made?

Comment: No configuration changes needed.It's is the main cause.I also faced so many times this kind of issue